# Importing into SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, truncate

[Import.csv](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11906589/farashat.csv)

I am using Import Wizard to import this excel file into sql but everytime no matter what i try i receive a truncation error resulting in not importing it obviously.

```
- Executing (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 0" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "Column 0" (10)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Column 0" (10)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:\Users\crover\Downloads\فراشات حواء-2\farashat.csv" on data row 17.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

The database collation is Arabic_CS_AI while import wizard has the code page property set to 1256 with the Unicode unchecked.

Comment: using BCP or SSIS/import data wizard? What is the process and the exact errors please. Truncate errors should include a column name/ordinal and a line number

Comment: what is the DDL of the table, if you don't increase the size of the columns, you will never be able to import this file

Comment: @Paul I am using import data wizard already and the destination table is generated automatically while importing and the destination column types are all set to nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: @SQLMenace I am using nvarchar(MAX) for the destination

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when you receive a truncate error, it is because one of the columns you are importing your data to is not big enough.

Removing the trailing and leading spaces might help with this problem.

Comment: I am using nvarchar(MAX) for the destination

Comment: Arabic_CS_AI for database while the code page is 1256 (Ansi - Arabic) while importing